# Bootstrap 4 Card with right text?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need the text to be located to the right of the image and that's it. How to do it?
**maket**
[image: maket]

Answer (score 1):

In the Bootstrap 4 documentation, it describes how to use horizontal cards: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#horizontal